# Is it a waste of time to use "Build Automatically" option for Java projects in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, build, rad

I'm developing J2EE webapps in Eclipse (RAD, actually). I've always used the "Project > Build automatically" option. However, I noticed that this isn't always necessary because Eclipse seems to push out changes to my server when I save a file. This works great but I'm wondering why this would be checked by default.

I can think of a few times when it makes sense to fully build and deploy the app:

- After changing a XML configuation file that gets loaded at app startup (application.xml, web.xml, bean configuration xml files, etc)
- After changing a static variable on a class

Other than this, I can't think of other times when it would be crucial (or useful) to enable the build automatically option. Am I incorrect in my above assumptions? Am I just wasting a bunch of time by building automatically??

Comment: Are you sure it deploys automatically, too? That sounds like a bug/problem. It should only compile classes and do other stuff within Eclipse itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automatic build compiles in the first-place. You can disable the automatic publishing (see screen) if you double-click on the server in the server-view. The automatic publishing has nothing to do with automatic build.[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. Turning off automatic publishing helped a lot. Since I read your answer I have saved a lot of time by turning off automatic publishing.  However, I didn't realize that Build Automatically is really for the benefit of the IDE's code-completion and error-checking facilities - it is best to leave that turned on. Thanks for your prompt answer.

Comment: Erro checking maybe, but code completion works off of your sources regardless of what's been compiled.